# Difference between 2 sd cards

Tags: hardware, sd-card

What is the difference between this card [Sandisk extreme 32 go](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B0718WYG9V/ref=s9u_simh_gw_i2?ie=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B0718WYG9V&pd_rd_r=597c46d9-078d-11e8-a008-71ec069f688d&pd_rd_w=PRY0C&pd_rd_wg=qatt4&pf_rd_m=A1X6FK5RDHNB96&pf_rd_s=&pf_rd_r=9FJ1BZ26WSRX0C2YQG4Z&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=b2aa2a3e-4691-4349-8b50-65f9675cdf61&pf_rd_i=desktop) and this [Sandisk extreme 32 go](https://www.amazon.fr/M%C3%A9moire-microSDHC-SanDisk-Extreme-Adaptateur/dp/B06XWMQ81P/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1517516598&sr=1-1&keywords=microsd%2032%20go%20extreme). Just FFP write in the first, what is FFP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No difference. This is only related to Amazon package : FFP =  "Frustration Free Packaging"